# Cannot get body from DELETE request with Slim Framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, slim

I'm working in an app using backbone.js and Slim Framework.
The issue is here: I need to delete a record by executing a MySQL stored procedure that receives, besides the ID of the record to delete, another parameter to execute some business logic.
The problem is that I only receive the ID of the record. My $app->request()->getBody(); is blank.
Here is the code:

/rest/folder/index.php

```
<?php
require_once '../../vendors/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app -> get('/categories/', function() use ($app) {
    require_once ('../../libs/auth.inc');
    $auth = new Authentication();
    $user_id = $auth -> SessionAuthenticate();

    require_once ('categories.php');
    $categories = new Categories();
    $categories -> getCategories($app, $user_id);
});

$app -> post('/categories/', function() use ($app) {
    require_once ('../../libs/auth.inc');
    $auth = new Authentication();
    $user_id = $auth -> SessionAuthenticate();

    require_once ('categories.php');
    $categories = new Categories();
    $categories -> saveCategory($app, $user_id);
});

$app -> put('/categories/:category_id', function($category_id) use ($app) {
    require_once ('../../libs/auth.inc');
    $auth = new Authentication();
    $user_id = $auth -> SessionAuthenticate();

    require_once ('categories.php');
    $categories = new Categories();
    $categories -> saveCategory($app, $user_id);
});

$app -> delete('/categories/:category_id', function ($category_id) use ($app) {
    require_once ('../../libs/auth.inc');
    $auth = new Authentication();
    $user_id = $auth -> SessionAuthenticate();

    require_once('categories.php');
    $categories = new Categories();
    $categories -> deleteCategory($app, $user_id, $category_id);
});

$app -> run();
```

Here is my delete function on /rest/folder/categories.php

```
public function deleteCategory($app, $user_id,$category_id) {
    $requestBody = $app->request()->getBody();
    $params = json_decode($requestBody, true);

    $agreement_id = $params['agreement_id'];

    $con = $this->conectarDB();
    $query = "CALL SPD_CATEGORIES($category_id,$agreement_id);";

    //print_r($query);

    $result = $this->con->query($query);    
    $this->con->close();
    $app->status(200);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

And here is my backbone delete function on /modules/folder/CategoriesView.js

```
confirmDeleteForm : function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var category_id = $('#categories_select').select2("val");
    var self=this;

    this.category = this.categories.findWhere({'category_id':category_id});
    var agreement_id = this.category.get('agreement_id');

    $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');

    this.category.destroy({
        data: {
            'agreement_id': agreement_id,
        },
        processData : true,         
        success: function(model, response) {

            self.cleanForm();
            self.getCategories();
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            if (response.status == 500) {
                self.showErrorMessage('Se produjo un error en el servidor', 'ERROR');
            } else {
                self.showErrorMessage(response.responseText, 'ATENCION');
            }
        }
    });

},
```

In the model destroy I tried to add DATA: and HEADERS: but none of the work.

Is it possible to be made?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've found this: [Slim v2](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/custom/#one-route-custom-http-methods)
 as referred in first answer.

and this: [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) (BACKBONE.ROUTER title)

This is what I'm trying now. I really can get to work, but I think this is the way to resolve the issue I'm having.

**UPDATE 2**

Still can figure out how to do this. So, because of my almost-here deadline, I changed the database structure to only delete with a row ID.
I will keep trying this after finishing the project.

Thanks.

Comment: You could also try to add 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' to headers.

Comment: +Davide Pastore I'm still trying. I think this is one way. Thanks. I'll let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/delete/#method-override?

> Unfortunately, modern browsers do not provide native support for HTTP
> DELETE requests.
>
> ...If you are using Backbone.js or a command-line HTTP client, you may also override the HTTP method by using the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read that before, but couldn't make it work. Can you give me an example in my code? Or perhaps linking me to it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly I haven't used Backbone before.  I personally just stick to `GET` and `POST` methods for web applications, and use parameters like `categories/1/delete` to handle other access modes.  Not the most RESTful, I know...but seems the most transparent and straightforward.  I still don't understand why HTML5 dropped support for `DELETE` and `PUT`.

Comment: btw, if you put a body on the DELETE, you'll run into trouble if you try to use Akamai and various other CDNs.  Akamai for sure doesn't bother to pass through the body of a DELETE, as the RESTful convention is not to have one.